# Why are markers not displayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display markers after the map is displayed.  I am unable to do so.. regardless of any error.  I have assured that the snapshot is with the data and marker array is nicely created. is there any logical error?? please help.

```js
var apps = angular.module('appa',['firebase','uiGmapgoogle-maps']);
apps.controller('mainCtrl', function($firebaseObject,$scope){

                var ref =  firebase.database().ref();
                var marker = [];
                ref.once("value")
                .then(function(snapshot)
                {
                snapshot.forEach(function(child)
                {
                  var mark = {
                  id: child.child("Id").val(),
                  coords: {
                  latitude: child.child("Lat").val(),
                  longitude: child.child("Long").val()
                  },
                  options: { title: child.child("Alt").val() }
                  };
    marker.push(mark);
                });
});

              $scope.map = {
                center:
                {
                  latitude: 67,
                  longitude: 24
                         },
                 zoom: 3
                      };
   });
```

```html
<body ng-app="apps">
    <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">

      <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in marker" coords="m.coords" options="m.options" idkey="m.id">
           </ui-gmap-marker>
                    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
<!--example-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

oh! I hot the answer my self. It was a simple mistake. I did not defined marker array in $scope. Therefore views were not getting what var marker is. I corrected it